# Almost sure equality of 0 and the index of a null set

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a real valued random variable, $I_A$ represents the indicator function,  and $A$ a null set, i.e $P(A)=0$, Is it true (without assuming that the random variable $X$ is bounded) that $XI_A=0$ almost surely.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Care to give a little explanation...

Comment: As a function on the sample space, $X I_A = 0$ on $A^c$, which has probability $1$.